# One xslt create xml file with I need transform one more time in other xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

My main question is: can I write an xslt transform in one file that will first extract the content from the CDATA section, and then in the same transform I will refer to this extracted content and create the actual data file?

Below is xml file:

```
<Docs>
  <Doc>
   <Content>
    <![CDATA[
      <Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Header DocNumber="1" Description="Desc1"></Header>
        <Poss>
          <Pos Id="1" Name="Pos1"></Pos>
          <Pos Id="2" Name="Pos2"></Pos>
        </Poss>
      </Doc>
   ]]>
  </Content>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Content>
    <![CDATA[
     <Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Header DocNumber="2" Description="Desc2"></Header>
      <Poss>
        <Pos Id="3" Name="Pos3"></Pos>
        <Pos Id="4" Name="Pos4"></Pos>
      </Poss> 
    </Doc>
  ]]>
 </Content>
</Doc>
```

First xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="Docs">
       <xsl:for-each select="Docs/Doc">
        <xsl:value-of select="Content/text()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get output

```
  <Docs>
    
      <Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Header DocNumber="1" Description="Desc1"></Header>
        <Poss>
          <Pos Id="1" Name="Pos1"></Pos>
          <Pos Id="2" Name="Pos2"></Pos>
        </Poss>
      </Doc>       
       
     <Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Header DocNumber="2" Description="Desc2"></Header>
      <Poss>
        <Pos Id="3" Name="Pos3"></Pos>
        <Pos Id="4" Name="Pos4"></Pos>
      </Poss> 
    </Doc>
  
 </Docs>
```

But I need data from this output and pass through it on other xslt and then get output something like this:

```
    <DOCS>
      <DOC NUMBER="1" DESC="Desc1">
      <POSS>  
        <POS>Pos1</POS>
        <POS>Pos2</POS>
      </POSS>
      </DOC>
      <DOC NUMBER="2" DESC="Desc2">
      <POSS>  
        <POS>Pos3</POS>
        <POS>Pos4</POS>
      </POSS>
      </DOC>
    </DOCS>
```

When I tried to apply the second transform in the same xslt file to the xml output which is the result of the first transform, it didn't work, it's the way i needed. How to do it?

Comment: You can do that easily in XSLT 3.0 as it offers a `parse-xml` function (and a `parse-xml-fragment` function) so there you can easily parse the CDATA which shows up as a text node in your input tree, get a tree of nodes as the result which you further process. Any XSLT 1 workarounds depending on disable-output-escaping are known to work only if you use two separate transformations and it is ensured the first result is serialized.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case I am stuck with xslt 1.0. Can I do this in 1.0?

Comment: As I said, with two different transformations where the first outputs the CDATA section (using disable-output-escaping) and you can ensure that result is seriaized, then feed the serialized result as the input to the second transformation you can do that with pure XSLT and whatever script or programming language you use to run XSLT. Within pure XSLT 1 and a single transformation this is not possible unless you can use or integrate platform/processor specific extension function doing the `parse-xml`.